# How to use more than one color in a tellraw command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using `/tellraw` for my server, and I know how to use tellraw with color, but not with multiple colors in one command. Help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This command would send the letter 'r' in red and the letter 'b' in blue. (You would replace *player* with a username or target selector).

```
/tellraw player [{"text":"r", "color":"red"}, {"text":"b", "color":"blue"}]
```

This one would write, "Hello, World!" with two different colors:

```
/tellraw player [{"text":"Hello, ", "color":"gold"}, {"text":"World!", "color":"red"}]
```

[This page](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/351959-1-8-raw-json-text-examples-for-tellraw-title-books#EXTRA) will show you more about raw JSON text and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want long ones try this one:

```
/tellraw @a [{"text":"YOU ","color":"gold"} ,{"text":"HAVE ","color":"aqua"} ,{"text":"BEEN ","color":"blue"} ,{"text":"REWARDED ","color":"green"} ,{"text":"GREATLY","color":"yellow"} ,{"text":"!!!!!!","color":"dark_purple"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [minecraftjson.com](http://www.minecraftjson.com) it helps! You can add multiple lines and copy and paste the code provided in the box after you have finished